# How do you sort a column by custom order in a pivot table in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

In google sheets, I have a column with month name and it requires me to sort it either in alphabetical ascending or descending order. I need to custom sort it so it'll show jan, feb, mar, etc.  How do I do this in Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a month's name as a text string. Instead, make a column that has a date with that month (e.g. `=date(2000, <month>, 01)` and apply a date format for its values that shows only the month part.

Then use the sort in ascending or descending order, it will work as intended.

Comment: While this solves this one specific case, it would be more useful to more people to provide an answer to the general case of "can I sort pivot table columns manually in Google Sheets".